# How do I store an object's position from the previous frame in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to figure out why this code isn't working like I thought. The "lastPosition" variable is always the same as the "currentPosition" variable, although I thought I cached the transform.position on the current frame within the "currentPosition" variable. I feel like it's a very simple error, but I'm not sure where. Here is my code:

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float moveSpeed = 2f;
 
    [SerializeField]
    private float currentSpeed;
 
    private Vector3 lastPosition;
 
 
    [SerializeField]
    private float strengthMultiplier;
 
    [SerializeField]
    private float strengthDiminisher = 7000f;
 
    private bool isRollingForwards;
 
    private bool isRollingBackwards;
 
    private bool isRollingLeft;
 
    private bool isRollingRight;
 
 
    private void Start()
    {
        lastPosition = transform.position;
    }
 
    private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 inputVector = new Vector2(0, 0);
 
        Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
 
 
        currentSpeed = (currentPosition - lastPosition).magnitude / Time.deltaTime;
 
 
        strengthMultiplier = currentSpeed / strengthDiminisher;
 
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            inputVector.y = +1;
        }
 
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            inputVector.y = -1;
        }
 
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            inputVector.x = -1;
        }
 
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            inputVector.x = +1;
        }
 
       
        inputVector = inputVector.normalized;
 
        Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0f, inputVector.y);
 
        Vector3 playerVelocity = (currentPosition - lastPosition) / Time.deltaTime;
 
        Vector3 playerDir = playerVelocity.normalized;
 
     
 
        isRollingForwards =  currentPosition.z > lastPosition.z;
 
        isRollingBackwards = transform.rotation.x < 0f;
 
        isRollingLeft = transform.rotation.z > 0f;
 
        isRollingRight = transform.rotation.z < 0f;
 
 
        transform.position += moveDir * moveSpeed * strengthMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;
       
 
        lastPosition = transform.position;
 
    }
 
    public bool IsRollingForwards()
    {
        return isRollingForwards;
    }
 
    public bool IsRollingBackwards()
    {
        return isRollingBackwards;
    }
 
    public bool IsRollingLeft()
    {
        return isRollingLeft;
    }
 
    public bool IsRollingRight()
    {
        return isRollingRight;
    }
}
```

I tried caching the last position and the current position of the object, but they are always the same.

Comment: The last thing in `Update` is saving the old position. The first thing in Update is saving the current position. What would change it between those two points in time? The only place I see is here `transform.position += ...` You probably want `lastPosition = currentPosition;` instead of `lastPosition = transform.position;` if you want to save what it was before the current update modified it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Unity's `LateUpdate()` function for this. What LateUpdate() does is that it executes everything inside that function after the `Update()` function is called. So basically, it executes the code at the end of a frame. (Not exactly at the end of the frame but you get the idea).

What you can do is something like this:

```csharp
void Update()
{

    currentPosition = transform.position

}

void LateUpdate()
{

    //Make sure that lastPosition and currentPosition are both Vector3, then you can set it
    lastPosition = currentPosition;

}
```